# Replacing/repairing old box window

Tags: windows

We have an old box window in the kitchen (opening is about 58'' x 44.75''). They are double windows and both sides have cracks so we are thinking about different options to replace or repair them. Does it make sense to repair them? Or should we invest in new box or bay windows? What are rough costs of different options?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This window actually looks like a replacement window since it's different from the older on below. I have to guess it would be cheaper to repair it than replace it completely. Just my humble opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repair will certainly be much cheaper than replacement. I recently installed a new garden window, which was oly 32x36" and the window cost over $600. Yours is even bigger. I'm guessing a local glass company could replace the broken glass for ~$200 or less--certainly no where near the cost of a complete replacement. Good luck!